# Js event object is not being send via peer to peer connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I am trying to implement cobrowsing  [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobrowsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobrowsing)
.

I am implementing it as follows:-

1. Establish peer to peer connections.
2. Send js event object from one peer to another.(like click object)
3. simulate the received event at other peers.

I have successfully established peer to peer connection.

Now I am capturing the js event at one end as follows :-

```
document.getElementById('mimic').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            document.getElementById('mimic').style = 'color:red;';
            dataChannel.send(e);
        }, true);
```

at other ends I am recreating the event as follows:-

```
receiveChannel.onmessage = function(event){
                    var target = event.data.target;
                    target.dispatchEvent(event.data);
                  };
```

The issue is that the event is not recreating.

I thought that the issue might be with sending of event object. so I thought of sending the event object as a string. but I encountered a strange behavior.

If I console log the event object i.e. `console.log(e);` I get:-

```
click { target: <button#mimic>, buttons: 0, clientX: 29, clientY: 169, layerX: 29, layerY: 169 }
```

if I stringify event object i.e `console.log(json.stringify(e));` I get:-

```
{"isTrusted":true}
```

I can't understand why stringify is showing such a behavior.

NOTE :-
available cobrowsing solutions are costly and the open source once are not feature rich.

I have already researched them all.

In case any one thinks I am doing it the wrong way, feel free to point me out.

Comment: I didn't know that _pears_ were able to send any data \*.\* !

Comment: _"simulate the received event at other pears."_? Did you mean other apples?

Comment: We can send data through webRTC using RTCDataChannel. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-rtcdatachannel

Comment: BTW you can't propagate the event because the target is NOT the same on each sides, even if they come from the same code. IMO you should be sending the ID of the targetted object and the data attached to finally propagate the event (or directly call the right method ?) to the element designed by the ID you sent.

Comment: @Cerbrus I meant pear only. I am using web RTC for pear to pear connection. so in case one pear does any click or say scroll, then the information about the scroll would be send to all connected pears.

Comment: @rahul: I case you didn't get the hint: [This is a _"Pear"_](https://www.google.nl/search?q=pear&tbm=isch). What you're talking about is a _"Peer"_.

Comment: @Cerbrus OOPs I would correct it. LOL

Answer (score 1):

No you can't send event like itself!
the message/object sent over datachannel will be serlizalied and some objects like dom elements cannot be serialized. you can send data like:

```
var obj = {type : 'click'};//init your object as the known format
dataChannel.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

and receive message like that :

```
dataChannel.onmessage = function(e){
  var json = JSON.parse(e.data);

  var type = json.type;
  //write your logic based on the json object format
  //..............
}
```

in between the e.target is different from one page to another! you can't send an element from one to another, you may sent its **id** value and select target element on the other peer's html page.